# Наследование в JavaScript в через прототипы

Tags: javascript, ооп, веб-программирование

При изучении JavaScript возник вопрос:

Почему при наследовании на основании прототипов нужно делать так:

```
child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
```

а нельзя просто сделать так:

```
child.prototype = parent
```

Разве не одно и тоже получаем?

Answer (score 2):

В иерархии прототипного наследования есть 2 типа сущностей - это прототипы(объекты) и конструкторы(функции)

```js
function Parent() {this.name = 'Parent'; this.foo='foo';}
Parent.prototype.getName = function(){return this.name;};
Parent.prototype.getFoo = function(){return this.foo;}

// Заведём функция для теста дочерних "классов"
function newtest(Ctor) {
  var test = new Ctor;
  try{
    console.log(test.getName(), test.getFoo(), test instanceof Ctor, test instanceof Parent);
  } catch(e) {console.error(e.message);}
  return test;
}

// Здесь прототипу конструктора присваивается конструктор, функция,
// у которой нет свойств, которые мы ожидаем увидеть в иерархии
function Child1() {this.name = 'Child1';}
Child1.prototype = Parent;  
newtest(Child1); // test.getName is not a function!

// Здесь прототипу присваивается объект, созданный на базе прототипа родителя, 
// у него есть все свойства/методы, которые мы объявили в Parent.prototype
function Child2() {this.name = 'Child2';}
Child2.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);  
newtest(Child2); // Child2 undefined
// конструктор родителя не был выполнен


// Непосредственный вызов конструктора, неприменимо,
// если конструктор родителя имеет параметры 
// либо зависит от внешних факторов/имеет побочные эффекты
function Child3() {this.name = 'Child3';}
Child3.prototype = new Parent;  
newtest(Child3); // Child3 foo

// Вызов родительского конструктора из дочернего
function Child4(){
  // this.constructor.call(this); // возможно, потому что св-во constructor у нас сломано - указывает на родительский конструктор
  Parent.call(this);
  this.name = 'Child4';
}
Child4.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
newtest(Child4); // Child4 foo

// Иногда бывает важно восстановить свойство prototype.constructor в заменённом Child.prototype
Child4.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype, {
  constructor: {value: Child4, enumerable: false, writable: true, configurable: true}
});




// Наиболее распространённая форма наследования до появления Object.create
// подразумевала создание промежуточного конструктора:
function extend(P, C) {
  var F = function (){};
  F.prototype = P.prototype;
  // заменяем прототип вновь созданным объектом с прототипом родителя
  C.prototype = new F();
  // восстанавливаем свой конструктор
  C.prototype.constructor = C;
  // ссылка на родительский конструктор, чтобы отвязаться от его имени
  C.prototype.super = P;
  // Лучше последние 2 свойства задать через Object.defineProperty, чтобы выставить enumerable: false
}

function LegacyChild() {this.super(); this.name = 'LegacyChild';}
extend(Parent, LegacyChild);
newtest(LegacyChild); // LegacyChild foo
```

Answer (score 0):

Если по простому и по русски, то делая `child.prototype = parent.prototype` ты не создаешь новый объек "прототип" ребенка... Не забываем, что в JS обекты передаются по ссылке и в таком случае твой дочерний объект прототипа будет лишь ссылаться на родительский по ссылке. И при добавлении свойств и методов в дочерний (специфические только для него), они так же будут доступны и в родительском.
`child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);`  Делая так, ты создаешь новый обект.